# Examples for DPLL backward chaining algorithm

Tags: algorithm, logic, artificial-intelligence, inference

I am working on a program to simulate the DPLL backward chaining algorithm. I have tried to find an example that explains how it is implemented or applied on a set of clauses but in vain. Pseudo-code is all well and good, but on their own aren't very explanatory.